# Formula Assistance

Tags: visual-workflow, variable

I am creating a formula variable in a Flow but keep getting this error. Crop net Acres is a Number field.

```
IF(
    ISBLANK( [Opportunity].Crop_Net_Acres__c),
    0, 
    ( [Opportunity].Crop_Net_Acres__c)
)
```

**Error Message:**

> netAcresFormula (Formula) - The formula expression is invalid: Syntax error. Missing '='

Any thoughts here?

Comment: I don't have an answer for the error, but keep in mind you can also use the [`BLANKVALUE` function](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_a_h.htm&type=5), it's a little simpler for this use case.

Comment: The format for the formula you posted worked for me in a test formula field on an object.  But I've never used a Flow formula variable, so I don't what, if anything, might be different there to cause an issue.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong syntax for Flow formulas (you were using the Process Builder syntax)

Assuming this is a record-triggered flow on Opportunity, then $Record contains the flow interview's Opportunity.

```
IF(
  ISBLANK( {!$Record.Crop_Net_Acres__c}),
  0, 
  {!$Record.Crop_Net_Acres__c}
)
```

as @DavidCheng suggests you can do this [more concisely](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_a_h.htm&type=5)

```
BLANKVALUE(!$Record.Crop_Net_Acres__c},0)
```

When using the formula builder, be sure to click `Insert a Resource` which allows you to select from all available resources known to the Flow - the proper syntax then gets pasted in.